# How do you eager load all child collections an entity may have?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have this model:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Person Parent { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Person> Children { get; set; }
}
```

My question: how do I return all children, no matter how deep they are? For example, I could have a Person `Alice`, who has a child `Bob`, who in turn has a child `Charlie`. It's possible that this chain of parents and children goes on for 10 more Persons. Without knowing beforehand how many children Alice has, how do I return all of them in a query? I'm currently doing this:

```
 using (var ctx = new PersonContext())
{
    var result = ctx.People
          .Include(x => x.Parent)
          .Include(x => x.Children)
          .FirstOrDefault();
    return result;
}
```

But this doesn't seem to load `Charlie`. Using         `ctx.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;` also does not seem to make a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loading grand-children is not possible unless you know exactly the amount of children. So you either lazy-load them, or you can explicitly load them recursively... something like:

```
private void LoadChildren(DbContext context, Person person)
{
  var childCollection = context.Entry(person).Collection(x => x.Children);
  if(!childCollection.IsLoaded)
  {
    childCollection.Load();
    foreach(var child in person.Children)
      LoadChildren(context, child);
  }
}
/* ... */
using (var ctx = new PersonContext())
{
    var result = ctx.People
          .Include(x => x.Parent)
          .FirstOrDefault();
    LoadChildren(ctx, result);
    return result;
}
```

If you are ok with an approximation (having a "maximum" amount of grand children), *I think* you should be able to do this using the string format of `Include` (totally untested though, just posted this for you to experiment):

```
/* ... */
var numOfGrandChildren = 30; // 30 maximum grandchildren
string childInclude = "";
for(var i = 0; i < numOfChildren; i++)
{
   if(childInclude != "") childInclude+=".";
   childInclude+="Children";
}
using (var ctx = new PersonContext())
{
    var result = ctx.People
          .Include(x => x.Parent)
          .Include(childInclude)
          .FirstOrDefault();
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I think that this is the correct answer by the way! Upvoted ++

Comment: Include will always bring in all related entities, So i think the above query will return all child of the first people

Comment: @Eldho yes, but OP's problem is second/third/etc. levels, or so I understood from the question (meaning: the first person will have children, which will have children in turn, which may have others, etc.), and he wants to load them all

Comment: Thank you for describing the problem @Jcl

Answer (score 1):

You can disable lazy loading for a navigation property by making it non-virtual:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/data/jj574232.aspx#lazyOffProperty

So your class would be:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Person Parent { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Person> Children { get; set; }
}
```

You can disable lazy loading for an entire context through configuration:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/data/jj574232.aspx#lazyOff

```
public class YourContext : DbContext 
{ 
    public YourContext() 
    { 
        this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure how this answers the question? Since it has an upvote, I may have understood the question wrong, though

Comment: Marking a property as `virtual` allows (various) ORMs to override it with proxy classes (hence lazy loading), whereas I guess if you remove the `virtual` designator then all instances of that collection in the hierarchy will be eager loaded.

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but I'm not sure the OP is asking anything about lazy loading (except the last test where he disabled proxy creation, but that has little to do with eager-loading and the question, in general)

Comment: I understood it as OP having a `Person` which includes a collection `Children`. When they explicitly includes the first level of the relationship using `.Include(x => x.Children)` it does not include the nested collections. Making this property non-virtual will ensure `Children` and all nested collections will be eagerly returned. It also means the explicit `.Include(x => x.Children)` is not required.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

first get all people then get the one you want.

```
using (var ctx = new PersonContext())
{
    var people = ctx.People.ToList();
    var result = People.Where(P=>P.Name == "Alice").FirstOrDefault();
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I think loading all possible people when you may need just 5 or 10 is a bit over the top. The solution works, definitely... but it's far from optimal